# spring social facebook accessToken with 400 error

Tags: spring-social

Hi please help am new to spring social,i am getting the 400 error while getting the access token from the AUTHORIZATION_CODE..

my code is as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/facebook", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
  @ResponseBody
  public Object getFacebookLoginPage(@RequestBody SocialCommand socialCommand) throws Exception {
      loggerService.debug("In ShareController", "getFacebookLoginPage method for facebook", "returns the JSON response for the input socialCommand");
      Result result = new Result();
      result.status = "OK";
      dataObject = socialCommand;
      FacebookConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new FacebookConnectionFactory(msgprop.getProperty("facebook.appId"), msgprop.getProperty("facebook.appSecrete"), msgprop.getProperty("facebook.namespace"));
      oAuth2Operations = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
      OAuth2Parameters params = new OAuth2Parameters();
      params.setScope(msgprop.getProperty("facebook.scope"));
      params.setRedirectUri(msgprop.getProperty("facebook.redirectURI"));
//        params.set("Content-Type", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.getType());
      String authorizeUrl = oAuth2Operations.buildAuthorizeUrl(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE, params);
      System.out.println(authorizeUrl);
      SuccessResponse successResponse = new SuccessResponse();
      successResponse.resultObj = authorizeUrl;
      result.response = successResponse;
      return result;

  }
```

and the callback controller is as follows

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/facebook/callback", params = "code", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public Object faceBookCallback(@RequestParam(value = "code") String callBackCode, Model model) throws IOException {
      loggerService.debug("In ShareController", "faceBookCallback method for facebook", "returns the JSON response for the input socialCommand");
      MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
      formData.add("client_id", msgprop.getProperty("facebook.appId"));
      formData.add("client_secret", msgprop.getProperty("facebook.appSecrete"));
      formData.add("scope", msgprop.getProperty("facebook.scope"));
      formData.add("redirect_uri", msgprop.getProperty("facebook.redirectURI"));
      formData.set("grant_type", "authorization_code");
      formData.set("Content-Type", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.getType());
      AccessGrant accessGrant = oAuth2Operations.exchangeForAccess(callBackCode, msgprop.getProperty("facebook.redirectURI"), formData);
      System.out.println(accessGrant.getAccessToken());
      appStatus.getActivityId();
      SocialCommand socialCommand = (SocialCommand) dataObject;
      socialCommand.setAppType("facebook");
      socialCommand.setAccessToken(accessGrant.getAccessToken());
      getImageLocation(socialCommand);

      model.addAttribute("activityId", appStatus.getActivityId());

      return "backToViewDetails";
  }
```

oAuth2Operations.exchangeForAccess giving the 400 bad request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things I notice...

First, why are you writing your own controller for performing the OAuth dance instead of using ConnectController that Spring Social provides? ConnectController can handle all of the redirects for you and has been part of Spring Social from the beginning. Spring Social Showcase (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase) is an example of a project that uses ConnectController.

Even so, assuming you have good reason for writing your own connection controller, I see nothing in getFacebookLoginPage() that performs the actual redirect to Facebook, so I can only assume that happens in code not shown. Then when the redirect comes back from Facebook, I'm puzzled as to why you set the content type and most of those parameters before calling exchangeForAccess(). (Even then, you're setting what looks like a request header, but you're setting it as a form parameter...not necessary, but also not what you had in mind.)

Again, I encourage you to take a look at ConnectController (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/blob/master/spring-social-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/connect/web/ConnectController.java). It will probably do what you need it to do. And even if you still feel the need to writing your own controller, you can look at how ConnectController works as a guide to how to write your own controller.

Comment: Does connect controller can be used for all the socials like facebook, twitter, tumblr and linkedIn etc..?

Comment: Here my social controller should be able to post/read actions with the access token generated from iphone, android and windows app which makes rest call to my controller. please can you help me the way which is better to configure my social controller.